# Installing wine uninstalls other programs

Tags: apt, wine, synaptic

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 ..Using apt and synaptic when trying to install apt says that I have broken packages and synaptic wants to uninstall programs that I use in order to install wine what is a good way to install wine with out going through the headache of removing packages just to have it installed?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel (= 4.2~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

the problem came because I needed to uninstall then reinstall wine for other purposes
this is not a duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) because I did not update Ubuntu. the problem its self came from having to reinstall wine not updating ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but after I installed `winetricks` via `apt` then installed `wine-devel` just fine. Not sure why it worked but it did.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, try 'sudo apt install -f' to fix the broken packages first.

After that, installing wine the regular way should work just fine.

Comment: this does not work

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: sudo apt install wine gives me wine is a virtual package and a spexific version needs to be specified. Then i do wine-devel because its the one that I prefer then it telles me it needs other wine versions installed but can't

Comment: try "apt install wine64-development".

Comment: that did not work either, I think its some weird dependency issue with wine apparently winetricks needs to be installed first in order to resolve them somehow.